# Please change the "ask the community to create a tag" link on the ask question page on per-site metas to not point to Meta Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags, asking-questions, per-site-meta

When tagging a question, there is a dialog box that shows up explaining the purpose of tags, and there's a link to ask the community to create a tag for you.

On main sites, this links to the relevant per-site meta, which is correct.

On per-site metas, however, this links to Meta Stack Exchange, which is incorrect; it should instead link to the per-site meta itself.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask -> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask -> https://meta.stackexchange.com/

**Original String:**

```
$createLinkStart$Create new tags$linkEnd$ or post without it and $askLinkStart$ask the community$linkEnd$ to create one for you.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have confirmed that this problem has been fixed in SOja.

---

[image]